# Similar Oracle query on MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm using oracle 11g with the following query:

```
with query1 as
 (select sysdate now,
         '020320322' contract,
         'Sergio' name,
         to_date('12/02/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt_test
    from dual
  union all
  select sysdate datetime,
         '020234322' contract,
         'John' name,
         to_date('12/12/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt_test
    from dual)
select * from query1;
```

How can I do similar in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with query1 as
 (select CURDATE() `now`,
         '020320322' contract,
         'Sergio' name,
         STR_TO_DATE('12/02/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') dt_test
    from dual
  union all
  select NoW() `datetime`,
         '020234322' contract,
         'John' name,
         STR_TO_DATE('12/12/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') dt_test
    from dual)
select * from query1;#
```

Returns

```
# now               contract    name    dt_test
2021-02-12 00:00:00 020320322   Sergio  2021-02-12
2021-02-12 00:19:50 020234322   John    2021-12-12
```